# AWS Api Gateway proxy compression "invalid block type"

Tags: amazon-web-services, gzip, aws-api-gateway

I have an Api Gateway endpoint set up as an `HTTP_PROXY`, and it is working as expected - so long as you don't provide the `Accept-Encoding: gzip` header. Then it fails. It seems that Api Gateway is doing "something" to the response which makes it indecipherable on the receiving end.

This is what I'm seeing:

- Sending the request directly to the proxy backend works as expected (e.g. `curl --compressed` completes successfully).
- Sending the request through Api Gateway with `curl --compressed` (and other ways) results in "invalid block type".
- The response from the proxy server is 17514 bytes, while through Api Gateway, it has been blown up to 31506 bytes. This is reflected in `Content-Length` headers.
- Api Gateway includes the `x-amzn-Remapped-Content-Length` header with the old (correct) value, so it seems to know it did *something* to the response.

The API method is configured as an HTTP PROXY, and looks like this:

```
aws apigateway get-method --rest-api-id xxxxx --resource-id yyyyy --http-method POST

{
  "requestModels": {
    "application/json": "MyRequestModel"
  },
  "authorizationType": "CUSTOM",
  "apiKeyRequired": false,
  "httpMethod": "POST",
  "methodIntegration": {
    "passthroughBehavior": "WHEN_NO_MATCH",
    "cacheKeyParameters": [],
    "requestParameters": {},
    "uri": "http://myproxy/api/v1/resource",
    "httpMethod": "POST",
    "requestTemplates": {},
    "cacheNamespace": "zzzzz",
    "type": "HTTP_PROXY"
  },
  "requestValidatorId": "xyxyxyxy",
  "authorizerId": "zyzyzyzyz"
}
```

As far as I can tell, there is nothing here indicating any mapping on Api Gateway's behalf. The UI also does not indicate any response mapping.

Testing the Api, I see the following:

- Response headers includes `"Content-Length":"17514"`, which is the expected value
- From the logs it *seems* like the Endpoint response body and the Method response body are the same, although it's a little hard to manually compare  two garbled ascii-representations of gzip data. Both `Content-Length` headers are the same as well.

During testing, the remapped content-length value is not visible anywhere, neither is the `x-amzn-Remapped-Content-Length` header. This leads me to suspect this is possibly being done by Cloudfront?

I get the same result both through "execute-api" and my custom domain mapping for this API.

Any pointers?

Comment: I don't believe CloudFront does any transformations, here, but you can take it completely out of the loop by deploying the API as regional rather than edge optimized.  At one point, API Gateway did not support `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` responses, which your origin may switch to when it sees `Accept-Encoding: gzip` since chunked transfer encoding would allow your origin to stream the gzipped response instead of buffering it until the `Content-Length` of the gzipped response was known.  What is `invalid block type` -- a console error from curl or an error message in the actual response body?

Comment: "invalid block type" is what curl says to `curl --compressed` when the response cannot be meaningfully decompressed. Piping the result to `gunzip` also does not work.

Comment: I think the workaround I identified before was to set a static request header of `Accept-Encoding: identity` in the Integration Request, but I haven't been able to find that answer and I'm not sure what the current state of affairs is as far as API Gateway and streaming responses.  The behavior you're describing does not sound familiar so even if that accomplishes the purpose, it may not be the optimal solution, because things may have changed.

Comment: What it's doing sounds like coercing the the binary payload to UTF-8 which would potentially replace anything identified as invalid characters (not all sequences of octets represent valid UTF-8) with the � Unicode replacement character, which has the bytes `0xEF` `0xBF` `0xBD` and would definitely scramble your gzip stream.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Michael-sqlbot! It was indeed utf-8 encoding of the response - see my own answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Michael suspected in one of his (very helpful) comments - this was indeed the case of API Gateway treating my gzip stream as UTF-8 encoded text, and re-encoded it. Given that this was an endpoint with no integration response mapping set up it seems very counter-intuitive that API Gateway would process my response in any way, but it is mentioned in the documentation.

The solution is to tell API Gateway that for this REST API, the `application/json` content type is "binary data". That causes API Gateway to pass the response along unprocessed. Instructing the REST API to do this with Cloudformation however, was a bit of a rabbit hole in itself, here's the solution:

```
RestApi:
  Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi'
  Properties:
    Name: !Sub 'agraNcdx${Environment}'
    BinaryMediaTypes:
      - 'application~1json'
```

Comment: > "but it is mentioned in the documentation". Can you point me to that documentation page? I think I'm having the same problem

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure how prominently it is featured - they just mention "by default the RestApi only supports utf-8 text" as a side-note with the binaryMediaTypes documentation, examples: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings.html and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/resource/rest-api/ (search for "UTF-8-encoded text")